# MongoDB slow writes causes socket time out exception

Tags: c#, performance, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am having performance issues with MongoDB.

Running on:

- MongoDB 2.0.1
- Windows 2008 R2
- 12 GB RAM
- 2 TB HDD (5400 rpm)

I've written a daemon which removes and inserts records async. Each hour most of the collections are cleared and they'll get new inserted data (10-12 million deletes and 10-12 million inserts). The daemon uses ~60-80 of the CPU while inserting the data (due calculating 1+ million knapsack problems). When I fire up the daemon it can do it's job about 1-2 mins till it crashes due a socket time out (writing data to the MongoDB server).

When I look in the logs I see it takes about 30 seconds to remove data in the collection. It seems it has something to do with the CPU load and memory usage.., because when I run the daemon on a different PC everything goes fine.

Is there any optimization possible or I am just bound to using a separate PC for running the daemon (or pick another document store)?

**UPDATE 11/13/2011 18:44 GMT+1**

Still having problems.. I've made some modifications to my daemon. I've decreased the concurrent number of writes. However the daemon still crashes when the memory is getting full (11.8GB of 12GB) and receives more load (loading data into the frontend). It crashes due a long insert/remove of MongoDB(30 seconds). **The crash of the daemon is because of MongoDB is responding slow (socket time out exception).** Ofcourse there should be try/catch statements to catch such exceptions, but it should not happen in the first place. I'm looking for a solution to solve this issue instead of working around it.

- Total storage size is: 8,1 GB
- Index size is: 2,1 GB

I guess the problem lies in that the working set + indexes are too large to store in memory and MongoDB needs to access the HDD (which is slow 5400 rpm).. However why would this be a problem? Aren't there other strategies to store the collections (e.g. in seperate files instead of large chunks of 2GB). If an Relational database can read/write data in an acceptable amount of time from the disk, why can't MongoDB?

**UPDATE 11/15/2011 00:04 GMT+1**

Log file to illustrate the issue:

```
00:02:46 [conn3] insert bargains.auction-history-eu-bloodhoof-horde 421ms
00:02:47 [conn6] insert bargains.auction-history-eu-blackhand-horde 1357ms
00:02:48 [conn3] insert bargains.auction-history-eu-bloodhoof-alliance 577ms
00:02:48 [conn6] insert bargains.auction-history-eu-blackhand-alliance 499ms
00:02:49 [conn4] remove bargains.crafts-eu-agamaggan-horde 34881ms
00:02:49 [conn5] remove bargains.crafts-eu-aggramar-horde 3135ms
00:02:49 [conn5] insert bargains.crafts-eu-aggramar-horde 234ms
00:02:50 [conn2] remove bargains.auctions-eu-aerie-peak-horde 36223ms
00:02:52 [conn5] remove bargains.auctions-eu-aegwynn-horde 1700ms
```

**UPDATE 11/18/2011 10:41 GMT+1**
After posting this issue in the mongodb usergroup we found out that "drop" wasn't issued. Drop is much faster then a full remove of all records.

I am using official mongodb-csharp-driver. I issued this command `collection.Drop();`. However It didn't work, so for the time being I used this:

```
public void Clear() 
{ 
    if (collection.Exists()) 
        { 
            var command = new CommandDocument { 
            { "drop", collectionName }
                };

                collection.Database.RunCommand(command); 
    } 
}
```

The daemon is quite stable now, yet I have to find out why the `collection.Drop()` method doesn't work as it supposed to, since the driver uses the native drop command aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The daemon is stable now, After posting this issue in the mongodb usergroup we found out that "drop" wasn't issued. Drop is much faster then a full remove of all records.

Answer (score 3):

Some optimizations may be possible:

1. Make sure your mongodb is not running in `verbose` mode, this will ensure minimal logging and hence minimal I/O . Else it writes every operation to a log file.
2. If possible by application logic, convert your inserts to bulk inserts.Bulk insert is supported in most mongodb drivers.
   http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Inserting#Inserting-Bulkinserts
3. Instead of one remove operation per record, try to remove in bulk.
   eg. collect "_id" of 1000 documents, then fire a remove query using `$in` operator.
   You will have 1000 times less queries to mongoDb.
4. If you are removing/inserting for same document to refresh data, try considering an update instead.
5. What kind of deamon are you running ? If you can share more info on that,it may be possible to optimize that too to reduce CPU load.

Comment: I am using the official 10gen MongoDB C# driver. So 1 check, 2 check, 3 check, 4 not possible :) 5 A custom daemon which downloads 241*2*~28000 auctions which are inserted. After that it tries to calculate the optimal way of composing multiple auctions to create new items (knapsack problem) (241*2*3560 records are calculated and inserted)

Comment: Could you elaborate why 4) is not possible? I don't see any problem there.

Comment: Well it's possible ofcourse, but it easier/faster to just truncate it instead of updating 20000 records. I just replaced removeall with a drop statement, but it doesn't matter much

Answer (score 2):

It could be totally unrelated, but there was an issue in 2.0.0 that had to do with CPU consumption. [after upgrade to 2.0.0 mongo starts consuming all cpu resources locking the system, complains of memory leak](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3822)

Comment: Updated my post. I am running 2.0.1 sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood, your application is crashing, not `mongod`. Have you tried to remove MongoDB from the picture and replacing writes to MongoDB with perhaps writes to the file system?

Maybe this will bring light to some other issue inside your application that is not related specifically to MongoDB.

Comment: Yea, you are right.. the application crashes due a SocketTimeOutException (I also edited my post to clarify the real problem). I've been thinking about making a storage medium myself, but since the complexity I already implemenented/depend (LINQ, etc) on, I would rather evade that.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen with SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  For me, it ended up being the network card.  The NIC was set to auto-sense the connection speed which was leading to occasional dropped/lost packets which was leading to the socket timeout problems.  To test you can ping the box from your local workstation and kick off your process to load the Windows 2008 R2 server.  If it is this problem eventually you'll start to see the timeouts on your ping command

```
ping yourWin2008R2Server -n 1000
```

The solution ended up being to explicitly set the NIC connection speed
Manage Computer > Device Manager > Network Adapters > Properties and then depending on the nic you'll have either a link speed setting tab or have to go into another menu.  You'll want to set this to exactly the speed of the network it is connected to.  In my DEV environment it ended up being 100Mbps Half duplex.

These types of problems, as you know, can be a real pain to track down!

Best to you in figuring it out.